# JavaScript not found in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I am trying to use JavaScript within my Django project. I have made a static folder within my app containing css and js folders, and whilst my css is working my js files are not. Any help would be great, thanks.

HTML:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css?{% now "U" %}"/>


<script type="module" src={% static "javascript/app.js" %}></script>
```

settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'musicPlayer',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    'musicPlayer/static/javascript/app.js',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a static *directory* to the `STATICFILE_DIRS` setting, **not** the full path:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
MUSIC_PLAYER_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'musicPlayer'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    MUSIC_PLAYER_DIR / 'static',
]
```

And in your template, you need to put double quotes around the `static` tag, and single quotes inside the tag:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}?{% now 'U' %}"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascript/app.js' %}"></script>
```

On a side note, I have never seen `type="module"` on a script tag before, so I'm not sure if that will work.  Generally its `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Thanks a lot that"s great, it works fine now. If I am using this javascript to try to play audio files that I also have in my static folder, do these also need to be in STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: @b_900 traditionally that would go in the **[`MEDIA_DIR`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#media-url)**, but you could put them in the `STATIC_DIR` if you want.  **Note** that if users can upload audio files then they **must** go in the `MEDIA_DIR`, or you will be open to *file inclusion* vulnerabilities.